# How can I dynamically add ObsevableCollection items to my window, and what is a proper container to hold them?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I need to add items from an `ObservableCollection` of a custom type to a window. I'm using MVVM so this collection is inside my ViewModel.

My collection:

```
public ObservableCollection<Record> RecordsToDisplay { get; set; }
```

Each record in the collection has X and Y coordinates (and other properties which are irrelevant for the situation):

```
public int X { get; set; }
public int Y { get; set; }
```

How can I add the the items in my collection to the window, considering their X and Y coordinates?

What container can answer this need?

How will the binding be performed?

**EDIT:**

The collection may change after loading data from a file, so I will need the container to handle that event.

Comment: What do you want to see in your window for each `Record` object in your collection?

Comment: For each record I want to display specific properties, such as name, icon, age, etc. There are also properties which I don't want to display

Comment: For each record - yes

Comment: Use a `DataGrid`, and use columns to display the properties you want to display.

Comment: That's what i currently do. But I don't want the `ObservableCollection` to be displayed in a list or a table.
I want each record in the collection to be displayed at its X and Y coordinates. The properties inside a record can be displayed in a list.

Comment: Somewhat like a chart that displays dots, where each dot is a record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a way to bind points in MVVM way to a canvas.

```
  <ItemsControl  ItemsSource="{Binding RecordsToDisplay}" BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="1" Height="200" Width="200">
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
             <Ellipse Fill="Red" Height="5" Width="5"/> 
          </DataTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas Background="Orange"/>
          </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Thank you, Items are now viewed properly :)
 Is there a way to hold two Data templates, where the chosen one is decided by a property of a record?

Comment: you can do it manually, place Ellipse inside grid and add two childerns, can control visibility through binding